# Finding a substring inside of a string and its slice?

Tags: python, string, indexing, substring

I've been trying to help my friend with his assignment and I can't even figure out where to start.  I can get it to identify the substring inside of the string but giving where it starts is troubling me. I've been at it for hours.  Any help is welcome. Here is everything I have about the assignment below.

PS. his entire class doesn't know how to do this. The teacher gave them something way out of their and my league.

#### Write a program that asks the user to input two strings stringA and stringB.

1. The program must first find all starting positions in stringA where stringB appears.

   For example if stringA is "`the car is in that carport`", and stringB
   is "`car`", the program should report that stringB occurs in stringA starting at positions 4 and 19
   (remember that the string
   starts at position 0).
2. Next the program must find all the starting positions in stringA where
   stringB almost appears.

   - What 'almost' means is that one of the letters of stringB does not
     match.
   - For example
     if stringA is the same as above, and stringB is "`the`", the program
     should report that
     stringB almost appears starting at position 14, which is the start of
     the string "`tha`".
   - Notice
     that it does not report that it almost appears starting at position 0,
     since there it appears
     with zero mismatches.
3. Finally, the program must find all the starting positions in stringA
   where the reverse of
   stringB appears.

   - For example, if stringA is the same as above, and
     stringB is "`rop`", then
     the program should report that the reverse of stringB appears in
     stringA starting at position 22.

The program equalsubstrings.py is helpful in understanding how to
write this program.

Answer (score 1):

```
stringA = "the car is in that carport"
stringB = "the"

exact = []
reverse = []
almost = []

lenA = len(stringA)
lenB = len(stringB)
limit = lenA - lenB
reversedB = stringB[::-1]

pos = stringA.find(stringB)
while pos >= 0:
    exact.append(pos)
    pos = stringA.find(stringB, pos + 1)

pos = stringA.find(reversedB)
while pos >= 0:
    exact.append(pos)
    pos = stringA.find(reversedB, pos + 1)

for i in range(limit):
    substrA = stringA[i:i+lenB]
    misses = 0
    for j in range(lenB):
        if substrA[j] != stringB[j]:
            misses += 1
    if misses == 1:
        almost.append(i)

print exact, almost, reverse
```

Comment: careful, you are about to get some down votes from the homework patrol.

Comment: @DTing: Yeah, maybe. I just thought an extra level of indirection (us giving hints to the guy trying to help) would make anything we say rather pointless.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you two clues:

In order to check if a string is a substring of another one, you can do:

1. Use [find](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.find):

> > > a="this is a test"
> > >
> > > b="test"
> > >
> > > a.find(b,0,14)

10

1. use the operator `in` like in the following example:

> > > a="this is a test"
> > >       b="test"
> > >       c="not related text"
> > >       b in a
> > >       True
> > >       b in c
> > >       False

To reverse a string, do something like the following:

```
>>> a="this is a test"
>>> a[::-1]
'tset a si siht'
```

Good luck with your homework

Comment: `in` is less helpful than `string#find`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the [re](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#module-re) module.

- `re.finditer` allows you to go through all the matches of a substring in a string.
- Each match will provide you with a "match object".
- Use `mo.start()` on any match object to find the index of that match into the string.
- For the "almost" matches, go through stringB char-by-char, replacing the current character with `[^<current_character>]`, and repeat the match procedure for each resulting regex, recording all matches.
- Lastly, do the simple search with the reverse of stringB (see elsewhere).

The benefit of this approach: You get a good grasp on `re` :-) .

BTW: What is the mysterious `equalsubstrings.py` program? ;-).